# Why does my state return a different value when it's inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently facing a weird problem in React Native right now. I have a simple component with a state and an onPress function that calls a Promise.

Let's just define state as:

```
this.state = {foo: 'bar'}
```

In the onPress function, I have:

```
onPress = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    promiseFunction()
    .then(()=>{
        console.log(this.state);
    })
}
```

So if I run this normally and press the button, I'll have the console log

```
bar
bar
```

Now, here's the weird part, let's just say that I have another button or another piece of code that changes the state of foo to "pomegranate", then I press the button, console now logs out:

```
pomegranate
bar
```

This behavior is very confusing to me since if anything, the initial call would return the original value if setState hasn't actually occurred yet, but the promise function should definitely have the updated value, shouldn't it?

Edit:
promiseFunction is really just a resolve that doesn't do anything. It's simply

```
promiseFunction = Promise.resolve(123)
```

Comment: promiseFunction should be resetting state back to bar, can you post that.

Comment: In this case, promiseFunction is really just a resolve that doesn't do anything. It's simply promiseFunction = Promise.resolve(123)

Comment: Please provide a working demo which illustrates the issue. Shouldn't be hard. Now it's all about guessing what might happen with asynchronous code to get such behaviour. Know one thing - `setState` is asynchronous and anytime you access `this.state` you can't know whether it is the latest

Answer (score 0):

By design promises run the executor function asynchronously. This includes creating a resolved/rejected promise.

Think of it as if your `Promise.resolve(23)` was a call to `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)`, which more or less would be doing this:

```
promiseFunction = () => {
    let thenCallback;
    let thenable = {
        then: (callback) => {
            thenCallback = callback;
        }
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
        // the executor function would be here but...
        // this mocks Promise.resolve so it's resolved right away 
        thenCallback(23);
    }, 0);

    return thenable;
}
```

do **not** use the code above, it's probably incorrect in many ways but it's there just to explain the control flow of a Promise.

Coming back to your issue, what's happening is that the code first runs your `console.log(this.state)`, as you invoke the promise the `.then` callback is put on the next event loop, your function call "returns" synchronously on the regular event loop tha is still running, then anything that was to happen after the call is done (like updating the component state!), and only then on the next event loop the `.then` part of your promise is called.

Hope this helps and doesn't make the explanation overly complex. Truth is that once you involve a Promise in your code you have to treat everything that comes after as asynchronous code, otherwise as in this case you might get undesired results due to things being executed out of order.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding this. Currently, the second console.log seems to be one event cycle _slower_ than the first console.log, even if both were called in the same event cycle?